Как написать комментарий с примером кода в Android Studio, чтобы не потерять угловые скобки?
Как написать комментарий с примером кода в Android Studio, чтобы не потерять угловые скобки?
У меня либо теряется вообще все внутри угловых скобок (скриншот 1), либо не отображается левая "<"
Вариант с &lt; не подходит, нужно, чтобы комментарии были читаемыми.



На enso предлагают использовать \<.
